# Can I use an Australia work visa for tourism?

Tags: visas, australia, change-purpose-of-travel, working-visas

I got a short-term work Australia visa subclass 400. Can I use the visa for tourism in Australia?

It was supposed to be used for a short job in WA, but it was postponed. The visa expiry is in Jan 2018.

Comment: Are you still planning to work with the visa, or do you want to use it *only* for tourism?

Comment: Unlikely to go Australia for the short time work as advice by sponsor company in AU. So i just want to use the visa to avoid any inconvenience of applying another visa in the future, (problem if I don't use the visa).

Comment: It's generally totally fine not to use visas, and much better than being caught using a visa for the 'wrong' reason.

Answer (score 3):

In general, no, as Department of Immigration and Border Protection notes that entry must be for the purpose that the visa was granted, and a holiday must be with coincident to that entry (added emphasis mine).

> [**Temporary Work (Short Stay Specialist) visa (subclass 400)**](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/400-)
>
> This visa lets you:
>
> - stay in Australia while your visa is valid (generally up to three months, but up to six months may be allowed in limited circumstances)
> - do short-term, highly specialised, non-ongoing work for which you were granted the visa
> - in limited circumstances, participate in an activity or work relating to Australia’s interests
> - bring members of your family with you to Australia, if they meet the requirements for including family members in your application. Your family members will not be allowed to work in Australia.
>
> We will tell you how many times you can enter Australia on this visa.
>
> **Combining a holiday with your intended work or activity may be allowed if the holiday is of short term duration and secondary to the main purpose of your visit**.

Comment: What happen if I don't use the visa, any consequences in future visa application?